# MVC 5 Determine if CheckboxFor is checked or not

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

While there are questions out there surrounding this topic, none answer them adequately.

Problem: I have a model with roughly 25 bool properties. Used as checkboxes. I'm looking for a way to determine if they're checked or not. Grab the name of that checkbox (or id) for database input.

My current way seems wildly inefficient. I grab the Id from the formcollection and have some conditional logic.

```
public ActionResult SubmitUwSelections(FormCollection form)
{
        var cbRating = form["cabRating"]; // Cab Raing ddl
        var filing = form["fileRqd"]; // filing required ddl
        var ifta = form["cbIfta"]; // IFTA cb
        var lossControl = form["lcRqd"]; // Loss control required cb
        var lossControlIf = form["lcInFile"]; // Loss control in file cb
        var app1 = form["AppInFile"]; //Application app in file cb
        var app2 = form["AppRqd"]; //Application app rqd cb
        var um1 = form["UMInFile"]; //UM in file cb
        var um2 = form["UMRqd"]; // UM rqd cb
        var terror1 = form["terrorInFile"]; // terror in file cb
        var terror2 = form["terrorRqd"]; // terror rqd cb
        var lossRun1 = form["LossRunInFile"];// loss run in file cb
        var lossRun2 = form["LossRunRqd"]; //Loss run rqd cb
        var inspect1 = form["cbVehicleInspectInFile"]; //vehicle inspect in file cb
        var inspect2 = form["cbVehicleInspectRqd"]; // vehicle inspect rqd cb
        var mvr1 = form["cbMvrInFile"]; // mvr in file cb
        var mvr2 = form["cbMvrRqd"]; // mvr rqd cb
        var loc1 = form["cbLocInFile"]; //Letter of Credit cb in file
        var loc2 = form["cbLocRqd"]; //Letter of Credit cb required
        var psComments = form["cifComments"]; //section 2 comment box
        var uniqPolicy = form["UniqPolicy"];
        var fileComplete = form["cbFileComplete"];


         //dto first section of FormCollection Form 
         if (ifta == null) { clDto.Ifta_Rqd = false; } else { clDto.Ifta_Rqd = true; }
         if (lossControl == null) { clDto.LossControl_Inspection_Rqd = false; } else { clDto.LossControl_Inspection_Rqd = true; }
         if (lossControlIf == null) { clDto.LcontrolInFile = false; } else { clDto.LcontrolInFile = true; }
         if (app1 == null) { clDto.ApplicationInFile = false; } else { clDto.ApplicationInFile = true; }
         if (app2 == null) { clDto.ApplicationRequired = false; } else { clDto.ApplicationRequired = true; }
         if (um1 == null) { clDto.UM_UimFormsInFile = false; } else { clDto.UM_UimFormsInFile = true; }
         if (um2 == null) { clDto.UM_UimFormsRqd = false; } else { clDto.UM_UimFormsRqd = true; }
         if (terror1 == null) { clDto.TerrorInFile = false; } else { clDto.TerrorInFile = true; }
         if (terror2 == null) { clDto.TerrorRqd = false; } else { clDto.TerrorRqd = true; }
         if (lossRun1 == null) { clDto.LossRunInFile = false; } else { clDto.LossRunInFile = true; }
         if (lossRun2 == null) { clDto.LossRunRqd = false; } else { clDto.LossRunRqd = true; }
         if (inspect1 == null) { clDto.vInspectionInFile = false; } else { clDto.vInspectionInFile = true; }
         if (inspect2 == null) { clDto.vInspectionRqd = false; } else { clDto.vInspectionRqd = true; }
         if (mvr1 == null) { clDto.MvrInFile = false; } else { clDto.MvrInFile = true; }
         if (mvr2 == null) { clDto.MvrRqd = false; } else { clDto.MvrRqd = true; }
         if (loc1 == null) { clDto.LocInFile = false; } else { clDto.LocInFile = true; }
         if (loc2 == null) { clDto.LocRqd = false; } else { clDto.LocRqd = true; }
         if (fileComplete == null) { clDto.FileComplete = false; } else { clDto.FileComplete = true; }
}
```

It's cumbersome and slow. Is there a better way to do this? A better way to check if they're checked or not? I have to insert all to a DB as true or false. Your help is definitely appreciated.

Comment: I agree that it is slow.  I usually at start of application create a List<CheckBox> and put all the checkboxes into the list.  Then enumerate through the list.

Comment: @ jdweng thanks for the input. I thought about that. Would I make a List of the model? Or something else? How do you isolate your checkboxes to just that list?

Comment: I just manually add them since the list never changes.  Adding 15 checkboxes in code is quick compared to searching form by name for each which is very slow.

Comment: IS there a specific reason for posting a formcollection and not a model to your controller? You are using mvc 5 right?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following in MVC. I assume you have a controller called UWSelectionsController, 2 actions (Index and SubmitUwSelections) and a model which i will call ChkBoxModel. So you have your model

```
public partial class ChkBoxModel
{
    public bool cbRating { get; set; }
    public bool filing { get; set; }
    public bool ifta { get; set; }
    public bool lossControl { get; set; }
    public bool lossControlIf { get; set; }
    public bool app1 { get; set; }
    public bool app2 { get; set; }
    public bool um1 { get; set; }
    public bool um2 { get; set; }
    public bool terror1 { get; set; }
    public bool terror2 { get; set; }
    public bool lossRun1 { get; set; }
    public bool lossRun2 { get; set; }
    public bool inspect1 { get; set; }
    public bool inspect2 { get; set; }
    public bool mvr1 { get; set; }
    public bool mvr2 { get; set; }
    public bool loc1 { get; set; }
    public bool loc2 { get; set; }
    public bool psComments { get; set; }
    public bool uniqPolicy { get; set; }
    public bool fileComplete { get; set; }
}
```

You have your 2 actions inside your controller

```
public class UWSelectionsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new ChkBoxModel()); ;
    }

    public ActionResult SubmitUwSelections(ChkBoxModel obj)
    {
        //access model bool (chkbox) parameter
    }
}
```

And finally you have your index.cshtml razor markup

@model WebApplication2.Controllers.ChkBoxModel

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitUwSelections", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(u => u.app1)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(u => u.app1)
    <hr />
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(u => u.app2)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(u => u.app2)

    //add the rest of the model ChkBoxModel properties here

    <hr />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

Now when you submit this form you don't have to check

```
if (ifta == null) { clDto.Ifta_Rqd = false; } else { clDto.Ifta_Rqd = true; }
```

you automatically know if something is selected or not by accessing the passed model, for example obj.ifta will be set as true or false. Home this helps.